# SurfaceView Canvas rendering at 1080p on 4K Android TV

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-tv

I'm attempting to use a `SurfaceView` to render a 3840x2160 bitmap on a 4K Android TV device (Nvidia Shield TV running Android 9) at native resolution.

According to the [Android 6 release notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0#4K-display), I should be able to set `preferredDisplayModeId` to a `Display.Mode` that supports 4K resolution in order to get my `SurfaceView` to render at 4K. However, it seems that even after setting `preferredDisplayModeId`, the `Canvas` provided to the `onDraw` method of my view is only 1920x1080. Attempting to draw the 3840x2160 bitmap to it results in the image being downscaled to 1080p, and then upscaled back to 2160p, losing information in the process.

Here's the relevant code from my `Activity`:

```kotlin
windowManager.defaultDisplay.supportedModes.forEach {
    if (it.physicalHeight == 2160 && it.refreshRate > 60) {
        val params = window.attributes
        params.preferredDisplayModeId = it.modeId
        window.attributes = params
    }
}

setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

My layout contains a custom view that extends `SurfaceView`. The custom view has an `onDraw` method that looks like this:

```kotlin
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(
        currentImage,
        Rect(0, 0, currentImage!!.width, currentImage!!.height),
        canvas.clipBounds,
        null
    )
}
```

`canvas.clipBounds` is `Rect(0, 0 - 1920, 1080)`, so when it tries to render the full bitmap, it has to scale it down to fit.

Here's some output of `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` when my `SurfaceView` is rendered:

```
Display 0 HWC layers:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Layer name
           Z |  Comp Type |   Disp Frame (LTRB) |          Source Crop (LTRB)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 com.google.android.tvlauncher/com.google.android.tvlauncher.MainActivity#0
  rel      0 |     Device |    0    0 3840 2160 |    0.0    0.0 1920.0 1080.0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 Dim Layer for - Task=580#0
  rel     -1 |     Client |    0    0 3840 2160 |    0.0    0.0   -1.0   -1.0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 com.android.tv.settings/com.android.tv.settings.MainSettings#0
  rel      0 |     Client |    0    0 3840 2160 |    0.0    0.0 1920.0 1080.0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 Background for -SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
  rel     -3 |     Client |    0    0 3840 2160 |    0.0    0.0   -1.0   -1.0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 Sys2023:dream#0
  rel      0 |     Client |    0    0 3840 2160 |    0.0    0.0 1920.0 1080.0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

Allocated buffers:
0x513aff00: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | Sys2023:dream#0
0x5333f300:    4.00 KiB |   16 (  64) x   16 |    1 |        1 | 0x1a00 | FakeFramebuffer
0x53340f80: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.android.tv.settings/com.android.tv.settings.MainSettings#0
0x53341280: 32400.00 KiB | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |        1 | 0x1b00 | FramebufferSurface
0x53341700: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.google.android.tvlauncher/com.google.android.tvlauncher.MainActivity#0
0x53341880: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.google.android.tvlauncher/com.google.android.tvlauncher.MainActivity#0
0x53341d00: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.android.tv.settings/com.android.tv.settings.MainSettings#0
0x53341e80: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.google.android.tvlauncher/com.google.android.tvlauncher.MainActivity#0
0x55d35480: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper#0
0x55d35900: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.android.tv.settings/com.android.tv.settings.MainSettings#0
0x55d35d80: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | Sys2023:dream#0
0x55d37580: 32400.00 KiB | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |        1 | 0x1b00 | FramebufferSurface
Total allocated (estimate): 137704.00 KB
```

For comparison, here's the same output when my app renders an `ExoPlayer` view, which is correctly rendering a 4K `SurfaceView`:

```
Display 0 HWC layers:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Layer name
           Z |  Comp Type |   Disp Frame (LTRB) |          Source Crop (LTRB)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
  rel     -2 |     Device |    0    0 3840 2160 |    0.0    0.0 3840.0 2160.0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 Sys2023:dream#0
  rel      0 |     Device |    0    0 3840 2160 |    0.0    0.0 1920.0 1080.0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

Allocated buffers:
0x513af180: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x513af300: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x513afc00: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x513afd80: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | Sys2023:dream#0
0x5333f300:    4.00 KiB |   16 (  64) x   16 |    1 |        1 | 0x1a00 | FakeFramebuffer
0x53340f80: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.android.tv.settings/com.android.tv.settings.MainSettings#0
0x53341280: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x53341400: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x53341700: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.google.android.tvlauncher/com.google.android.tvlauncher.MainActivity#0
0x53341880: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.google.android.tvlauncher/com.google.android.tvlauncher.MainActivity#0
0x53341a00: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | Sys2023:dream#0
0x53341d00: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.android.tv.settings/com.android.tv.settings.MainSettings#0
0x53341e80: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.google.android.tvlauncher/com.google.android.tvlauncher.MainActivity#0
0x55d35480: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper#0
0x55d35900: 8100.00 KiB | 1920 (1920) x 1080 |    1 |        1 | 0xb00 | com.android.tv.settings/com.android.tv.settings.MainSettings#0
0x55d35f00: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x55d36080: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x55d36200: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x55d36380: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x55d36500: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x55d36680: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x55d36800: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x55d36f80: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x55d37100: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
0x55d37280: unknown     | 3840 (3840) x 2160 |    1 |      12B | 0x900 | SurfaceView - Sys2023:dream#0
Total allocated (estimate): 72904.00 KB
```

You can see that the `SurfaceView` buffers when displaying `ExoPlayer` are correctly 3840x2160, but it doesn't seem to be allocating any `SurfaceView` buffers when using my custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Set the resolution of the SurfaceView before attempting to draw using the canvas.

```
getHolder().setFixedSize(3840, 2160);
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I would start using ExoPlayer to show stuff you need. It should be possible.

However, I dont think you are allocating the canvas correctly, I suppose are you using rect(args) with 4k included ? it seems either you are creating wrong canvas or because if you run on nvidia shield and afaik my shiled runs the android does on 1080p and the canvas gets that size if you request by getter is still old.

Easiest solution from my perspective is using the ExoPlayer.

Comment: The canvas is automatically allocated; I'm not manually creating it.